# How to run a specific migration of an accidentally dropped table

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, database-migration, knex.js

I accidentally dropped a table using the mysql command line. Luckily the table was empty.

But I need this table back. So I would like to re-run only the migration for that table, and not for other tables since these are still present.

When I run `knex migrate:latest`, it returns "Already up to date". The same if I `npm run migrate name-of-specific-miration-file`.

I use knex. How can I run only the specific migration file I want it to run?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it to work doing the following:

- On MySql command line: `create table my_table_name (hello text);`
- In terminal: `knex migrate:down name_of_migration_file.js`
- In terminal: `knex migrate:up name_of_migration_file.js`